# Semantic UI Dropdown - How to set default values with Angular JS scope?

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui, dropdown

I have a semantic ui multiple search dropdown and I need to set default values to it from some data from a database that is stored into the scope.

Dropdown code:

```
<div class = "ui multiple search selection dropdown" dropdown-search-personalities>
    <input type = "hidden"  >
    <i class = "dropdown icon"></i>
    <div class = "default text">Selecciona...</div>
    <div class = "menu">

    </div>
</div>
```

Directive code:

```
app.directive('dropdownSearchPersonalities', function () {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link : function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            $(elem).dropdown({
                allowAdditions : true,
                'set selected' : scope.studentPersonalities,
                onAdd: function (value) {
                    scope.addPersonality(value, scope.studentId);
                },
                onRemove: function (value) {
                    scope.removePersonality(value, scope.studentId);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

If i console.log the scope inside the directive I do get the information I want to use structured the following way:

[image]

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to set default values to the dropdown, since in the view its showing nothing.